# Does join limit in MySQL includes UNIONs?

Tags: mysql, join, restriction

Here is a [loin limits](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/joins-limits.html) in MySql. Does it applies fo joins with unions? For example:

```
SELECT * FROM TABLE1 JOIN ... //say 61 join here
UNION ALL
SELECT * FROM TABLE62 JOIN ... //and another 61 joins here
```

Does this workaround for join limit?

Answer (score 0):

`NO` join limit not apply on union. in this way you use 61+61 joins. 
because UNION or JOIN both are different operation of MySQL

Comment: Could you please share a link to documentation where this point is described?